# Where to save detailed user session information for EmberJS app?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am building my first EmberJS app, and am still trying to wrap my head around the best practices & conventions.  I'm using ember-data to talk to a RESTful API, and have [ember-auth](http://ember-auth.herokuapp.com/docs) working well enough to log in and save a user's ID & OAuth2 access token.  However, I'd now like to maintain additional user information (e.g. name, email, etc) for use in the navbar and in various other areas of the app.

To do this, I am thinking it would be helpful to have a User object (model) that is read from a separate endpoint (e.g. `/users/<id>`).  Since this info would be needed throughout the app, I'm inclined to store it on the `ApplicationController`, somewhat like [this example](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/#toc_storing-application-properties) from Ember's docs:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  // the initial value of the `search` property
  search: '',

  query: function() {
    // the current value of the text field
    var query = this.get('search');
    this.transitionToRoute('search', { query: query });
  }
});
```

However, my user object wouldn't quite be an action like `query` or a property like `search`, so I'm not sure this example applies.

I think I'll eventually want to call something like:

```
this.get('store').find('user', App.Auth.get('userId'));
```

but I'm just not sure where in the app that would go.

Main question: is the `ApplicationController` the right place for this information per Ember conventions, and if so, what might the code look like to retrieve it from the REST API?

Appreciate any thoughts to put me on the right track.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general approach that I've taken before is to store the currently logged in user as `App.CurrentUser`.  Then you can use it in any template.  Once I've pulled the `User` object I call `Ember.set('App.CurrentUser',user)` to store it, and then `Ember.get('App.CurrentUser')` to retrieve it in other routes or controllers.

Here's a short jsbin with the general idea : http://jsbin.com/ucanam/994/edit

Comment: Very helpful, this works perfectly, thank you!  One other note: I just found that ember-auth has some baked-in support for pulling a user model on login (see [docs](http://ember-auth.herokuapp.com/docs), "My app has a user model called `Member` that implements `find(id)`.").  Others may find that helpful as well.